# do relations work in ember fixture adapter?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, just trying to get a one to many relation working with ember data, using fixture adapters. Here it is on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/4716/edit?html,js,output

I don't see any output in the html from my {{each}} loop.

js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  topic: DS.belongsTo('topic')
});

App.Topic = DS.Model.extend({
  posts: DS.hasMany('post')
});

App.Topic.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    posts: [
      {
        id: 1,
        body: 'hey i am a post',
        topic_id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('topics', { path: '/' });
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>ember-latest jsbin</h1>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="topics">
    <h2>Index Content:</h2>
    <ul>
      {{#each topic in topics}}
        <li>{{id}}</li>
        {{#each post in posts}}
          {{body}}
        {{/each}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fixture Adapter doesn't support embedded relationships by default.  The easiest way to accomplish this is to set your relationships to be async and add them to the post's fixtures.

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  topic: DS.belongsTo('topic', {async: true})
});

App.Topic = DS.Model.extend({
  posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true})
});

App.Topic.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    posts: [1]
  }
];

App.Post.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    body: 'hey i am a post',
    topic: 1
  }
];
```

Here's your jsbin with it setup, http://jsbin.com/ucanam/4718/edit